# In InDesign, how to leave a fixed space from start of previous paragraph?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to apply a style to a title and have the next text start in the same vertical position everywhere i do this (a space before, but from the start, and not the end, of the previous paragraph).

Example:

```
      one page          another page
 __________________   _________________
|                  | |                 |
|  Chapter title   | | Very very big   |
|                  | |     title       |
|                  | |                 |
| Text start.      | | Text start.     |
|__________________| |_________________|
```

Can i do this without insert returns?

**Edit:**

I would prefer a solution that doesn't depend on text frame options, to allow adding new pages and not destroy the formatting of following pages.

Comment: Uh I'm pretty sure it can be done but I'm not clear on what you want. You want the spaces to be the same size? Or you want the body text to start at the same height regardless of the number of lines the title takes up?

Comment: I believe the only and possible best way is via separate text frames. You could always anchor the headline frame within the main copy frame.

Comment: @Scott thats what I was thinking with the Anchored Object

Comment: @Ryan I want the body text to start at the same height.

Comment: @Scott without using text frames, although can you explain how it would work with text frames ?

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you would do is set up a master page specifically for your chapter title page, and drag out a Primary Text Frame.

In the Text Frame Options, select the `Baseline Options` tab. Check `Use Custom Baseline` and set the `Start` option to the position at which you want your paragraph text to start. Leave `Relative To` set to "Top Inset" and make sure that `Increment Every` is set to the same value as your paragraph style leading.

[image: Text Frame Options]

Under `Indents and Spacing` in your Lead Paragraph style, set `Align to Grid` to "First Line Only" or "All Lines".

[image]

Make sure that the "Next Paragraph" style in your Title style is set to your Lead Paragraph style.

[image]

When you assign the Master Page to your chapter opener, you'll have a text frame into which you can type your title (using the title paragraph style). When you hit return the cursor will jump to the first baseline that you set in your Text Frame Options, regardless of how many lines there are in your title.

[image: Final Page]

Comment: This works, but i'm looking for a solution that doesn't depends on "Text Frame Options". This is because if i add text to the previous chapter and it forces a new page, then ALL the later chapter start will be messed up, and i will have to go everyone of them to apply the new "Text Frame Options" (and remove them from the text frame where the beginning of the chapter was).

Comment: Your chapter openers must be on right-hand (recto) pages, so under Keep Options in the paragraph style, set "Start Paragraph" to "On Next Odd Page." But you should be using the Book panel for a long, multi-chapter document, which would take care of this for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally set the shorter title with some «Forced line break», so they all have the same number of lines. Seams like an easy fix to me.